# Corona - Collision detection

Tags: lua, collision-detection, coronasdk, collision

I have a series of round objects defined as follows:

```
local myBalloon = display.newImageRect("images/cracker.png", 20, 20);
myBalloon:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint);
myBalloon.x = Random(50, _W-50);
myBalloon.y = (-10);
myBalloon.myName="balloon"
myBalloon.isSleepingAllowed = false;    
physics.addBody(myBalloon, "dynamic", {density=3.0, friction=1.0, bounce=0.0, radius=9});
```

I then have a single moveable oject defined as such:

```
local threeWay = display.newImageRect("images/3way.png", 80, 43);
threeWay:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint);
threeWay.x = (display.contentWidth / 2);
threeWay.y = (display.contentHeight -15);
threeWay.myName = "threeway"
pentagonShape = { -40,-5, 0,-22, 40,-5, 35,20, -35,20 }
physics.addBody(threeWay, "static", {density=4.0, friction=1.7, bounce=0.0, shape=pentagonShape});
```

I also have collision detection set up for the round objects like so:

```
function myBalloon:collision(e)
if (timeLeft ~= false) then
    if (playerReady == true) then
        if (e.phase == "ended") then
            if ( e.other.myName == "threeway" ) then
                audio.play(balloonPop);
                removeBalloons(self);
            end 
        end
    end
end
end
```

The collision work for the most part, but sometimes the round objects will land on the moveable objects and roll down for a little bit before being taken care of by the collision detection.

How do I provide a more instantaneous effect for the collision?
Do the attributes of the objects need to be different so there is more "force" on the collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "isSensor" as "true" on the baloon, this way it will trigger your collision function without bumping, rolling, etc...

:)

Comment: I added this and I still get the rolling behavior.

Comment: the baloon can ignore other things?

Comment: I figured it our. I was looking at the e.phase and doing the remove on "ended". I changed this to "began" and got the behavior I needed. It did not end up being the "isSensor" that fixed me up, but your last comment gave me the nudge to look at the collision event differently. Thanks speeder.